# Get order data when invoice is being create from admin

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, invoice

How to get order data of which admin is creating invoice.

I am using this code

observer call on `config.xml`

```
<events>
<sales_model_invoice_pay>
    <observers>
       <Karmick_Refer_Model_Observer>
          <type>singleton</type>
          <class>Karmick_Refer_Model_Observer</class>
          <method>changeStatus</method>
       </Karmick_Refer_Model_Observer>
   </observers>
</sales_model_invoice_pay>
</events>
```

`Observer.php`

```
<?php
class Karmick_Refer_Model_Observer{
public function changeStatus(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    $due = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice()->getOrder()->$order->getBaseTotalDue();
    Mage::log($due.'@@@');

}
}
?>
```

but it seems that nothing is being printed on log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching your event to `sales_order_invoice_pay`